# Filebeats saying dropping the line but still see in Kibana

Tags: logstash, elastic-beats

I'm working on **the ELK stack**. I'm trying to push the wso2 application logs to Elastic Search.

I configured Filebeats to read the lines that include `DCS`.

I see the `filebeats` log in the terminal as dropping the line doesn't match the pattern provided.

```
2020-06-25T01:43:10.557+0530    DEBUG   [harvester]     log/harvester.go:488    Drop line as it does not match any of the include patterns TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-25 01:43:01,725]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} -  Startup : syncUdaDataToUsage_OnlyOnce was removed from the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: usage-service-capp ]  {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker}
```

> But I see the same log in Kibana

[image]

> filebeats.yml

```
#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================

filebeat.inputs:


- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - C:\WORKSPACE\TransitionServices\wso2ei-6.1.0\repository\logs\wso2carbon.log

  include_lines: [' DCS ']


#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

  # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
  #reload.period: 10s

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false


#============================== Kibana =====================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]


#================================ Processors =====================================

# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```

logstsh-beat.conf

```
input {
    beats {
        type => "beats"
        host => "localhost"
        port => 5044
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => {"message" => "TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}%{SPACE}{org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{WORD:dataCollector}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:sequence}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{DATA:logMessage}=%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:responseMessage}%{SPACE}{org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}" }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "uda"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I don't understand why beats send a line if it doesn't match the pattern